# Is it possible to change the key of an app after it's been added to the store?

Tags: android, key

I looked at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html and it states that the key has to remain the same throughout the life of the app.

I was asked to create a signed release for testing and found out that the client added that test release to the store. Now they want to change the key for the final release. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible. Now that key is forever connected to the application ID used.

If they want to upload with a different key, you can change the application ID (for example, if it was `com.mycompany.myapp`, you can change to `com.mycompany.myapp2` and then release this new application with the correct key and disable the old one.

But change the existing one is not possible.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming.